# Chrome : bookmark that acts like a folder and a link

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is it possible to make a bookmark in Chrome that acts like a folder and a link ? Sometimes, you need a link about something in general and you want also crawl into more precise resources.

That is you can click it to open the specified url as a page and when hovering, it open a new menu where other bookmarks appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in chrome. There might be some extensions for this but this is very unlikely. But you can create a folder in the bookmark bar and than place all the link in it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

This bookmarklet is a bookmark with a URI starting with the pseudo-protocol
`javascript:`, followed by URI-encoded JavaScript code.

When you trigger the bookmark, the browser will run the code in the context of
the current page, for example to fill in your standard information.

For example, below is a bookmarklet that, when run, will look on the page
for an element with the ID of `someElement`  and, if found,
set its `value` property to `some value`:

```
javascript:(function(){var d=document,e=d.getElementById("someElement");e.value="some value";})();
```

Comment: Although it does not answer to the question, I did not know that and that's pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

Again, like said above, you need a bookmarklet. Here's one that could be useful:

```
javascript: 
siteweb = prompt('Enter Path:\n(leave blank for homepage)');
if(siteweb !== null){
    window.open('https://example.com/'+siteweb);
}
```

I'm assuming you want the site to be something else. Just change where it says https://example.com/ and **remember to put https:// at the beginning and a forward slash at the end.** Also, don't delete the quotes because the code needs them to work.

If you want something with different links, I can make that, I just need the links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

In abookmark (chrome/firefox extension), it is called url tag. A url tag can be clicked just as a url.

You can add url tags on a folder, and you can change a url bookmark into a folder with a url tag.

But the tags are not clickable in native bookmark manager.